# How to get the commit id of git while doing ansible deploy

Tags: git, deployment, ansible

I'm using ansible to deploy project, while deployment I do take last Commit Id of git so that in case of any problem I should be able to revert back.
The process of taking commit id is tedious and requires to login to remote server and getting the commit id.

Is there any way I can get the last commit Id from a remote server and it should log into local server. Before ansible deploys the latest code to remote.

Answer (score 7):

you could

```
- name: get git version
  shell: git rev-parse HEAD
  register: git_version

- name: store it
  shell: echo "last_git_version: {{ git_version.stdout }}" > host_vars/{{ ansible_host }}/git_info.yml
  delegate_to: localhost
```

and then, when you deploy your code you will have a variable with the latest `last_git_version` of the code you deployed that you could revert back to.

Comment: I get error trying this "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: git: not found"

Comment: either `git` executable is not installed in your system or the `PATH` env var is not set correctly. The first one can be solved with https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html and the second one can be solved with https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html

Answer (score 2):

I guess the better option is to:

- register the output of [git module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html)
- and use the `.before` key of the registered variable

An example could look like this:

```
- name: Clone git project
  git:
    repo: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker
    dest: /tmp/
  register: result_git_clone
- name: Print last commit ID
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ result_git_clone.before }}"
```

The expected output should be similar to:

```
TASK [nextcloud : Print last commit ID] ***********************************************************************
ok: [puigreig] => {}

MSG:

['476e60305b5f51aba863f0552cbaf7c2d4e0dbf9']
```

Comment: Great if you're using ansible to close the repo, but if you're acting inside an already cloned repo, then this doesn't quite work for that.